# Concatenate a number and a variable into a variable name for Jade

Tags: javascript, pug, template-engine

Say I have a set of variables name1, name2, name3... etc, which I'm writing out in a div.
Right now I can print it out using #{name1} #{name2} #{name3} etc but is it possible to do this with a for loop in Jade

`- for(var i = 0; i<3; i++)
{
    div #{"name" + i}
}`

So i want the output to be:

```
div #{name1}
div #{name2}
div #{name3}
```

Something like this in order to print out the first 3 elements.... hope i made some sense. When I do it the way I have above Jade seems to think I'm just putting a string into the div instead of the variable. If it matters I'm using Express.JS for my application. ty

Comment: Why not just make an array called `name` iterate over that instead of making separate variables?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

> Jade seems to think I'm just putting a string into the div

Because you are!

When you say "...instead of the **variable**" what you really mean is *a reference to its value*. This is what `for` loops excel at. But `"name" + i` creates a string and variables are not referenced as strings - with one important exception: object properties.

You have two choices:

```
var names = [name1, name2, name3];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) {
    div #{names[i]}
}
```

or...

```
var names = {
    name1: name1,
    name2: name2,
    name3: name3
};
for (var k in names) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(names, k)) {
        div #{names[k]}
    }
}
```